# Plot Set of Simulated Time Series in Grids

Tags: r, plot, grid

I want to plot the following set of time series in a grid arrangement.

```
set.seed(289805)
sd1_AR0.8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(671086)
sd1_AR0.9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(799837)
sd1_AR0.95 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(289805)
sd3_AR0.8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(671086)
sd3_AR0.9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(799837)
sd3_AR0.95 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(289805)
sd5_AR0.8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(671086)
sd5_AR0.9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(799837)
sd5_AR0.95 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(289805)
sd10_AR0.8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(671086)
sd10_AR0.9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(799837)
sd10_AR0.95 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
```

The above R code simulate `AR` time series with varying $\phi$ values in three levels ($\phi = 0.8, 0.9, 0.95$) and varrying `standard deviation` with four levels (sd = 1, 3, 5, 10).

I want the grid to be a `3 by 4` such that the first three (3) sets of series run in a row of three (3) columns.

I have tried to plot a single series like [image: this]:

```
set.seed(289805)
sd1_AR0.8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd1_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd1_AR0.8)))
p + geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

I rather want something like [image: this]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patchwork to the rescue. Read the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/vignettes/patchwork.html) to adjust titles, create 1 title, combine legends etc. etc.

```
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd1_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd1_AR0.8))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p2 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd1_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd1_AR0.9))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p3 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd1_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd1_AR0.95))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p4 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd3_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd3_AR0.8))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p5 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd3_AR0.9, x = seq_along(sd3_AR0.9))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p6 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd3_AR0.95, x = seq_along(sd3_AR0.95))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p7 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd5_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd5_AR0.8))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p8 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd5_AR0.9, x = seq_along(sd5_AR0.9))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p9 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd5_AR0.95, x = seq_along(sd5_AR0.95))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p10 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd10_AR0.8, x = seq_along(sd10_AR0.8))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p11 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd10_AR0.9, x = seq_along(sd10_AR0.9))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
p12 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = sd10_AR0.95, x = seq_along(sd10_AR0.95))) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Value') + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))


# plot in a 3 by 4 grid by using plot_layout
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11 + p12 + plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

[image]